# One URL pattern for two views?

Tags: django, forms

I am making simple blog application in Django. 
Here is it's [code](https://github.com/Anurag-Ans/JHTS/tree/master/blog).
I made a `comment` application in it, which works pretty well, but in my case the user would have to go to a different template *comment_form.html* (in my case) to submit the comment.
That's not good isn't it. So how would have an in-line form for a particular blog post(in *detail.html*).

Comment: What holds you back from putting it in one template? You can add as many context variables as you want.

Comment: You mean the add_comment view should render the detail template? I tried that but it was not working .

Comment: No, I mean to put it in ONE (1) template.

Comment: Could please provide me an example of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd pass the a CommentForm into the detail.html template, and that would render the form where you want it.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example ??